# Неправильно отрабатывает метод later() Mail фасада

Tags: php, laravel, email

В проекте (Laravel6.7) неправильно отрабатывает метод later из фасада Mail.
Очереди настроены в файле .env на database (QUEUE_CONNECTION=database)
Вместо того чтобы сделать задержку в n минут timestamp заносится в таблицу DB текущее время.
Кратко - нет задержки отправки емайла.
Ниже фрагмент кода

Mail::to(User::find(2)->email)->later("10",new ContactsMail($request->message,$request->email));

Answer (score 0):

Всё. Сам разобрался.
Mail::to(User::find(2)->email)->later(now()->addMinutes(10),new ContactsMail($request->message,$request->email));